# Is maximum principle valid in the case of non-smooth boundaries?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-functions

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be two bounded domains in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $U_1 \Subset U_2$. Note that we don't assume $\partial U_i$ to be smooth
or Lipschitz, they may be very bad.

Denote $U=U_2 \backslash \bar{U_1}$, consider the Dirichlet problem
\begin{equation}
\Delta u=0 \text{ on }U,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u=1 \text{ on } \partial U_1, \quad u=0 \text{ on } \partial U_2.
\end{equation}
Let
$$
U^r_1=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: d(x,U_1)\leqslant r\},
$$
$$
g_r=\max\{ 1-\frac{d(x,U_1)}{r}, 0\},
$$
an extension from $1,0$ function to a Lipschitz function defined on $\bar{U}$. By the standard argument, we can prove that there exists a
function $u \in W^{1,2}(U)$ satisfying the above boundary value problem and $u-g_r \in W^{1,2}_0(U)$. For different $r$ and different extensions, the solutions remain
unchanged, i.e. the solution is unique.

Now suppose $U_2 \Subset U_3$, consider the Dirichlet problem
\begin{equation}
\Delta v=0 \text{ on } U_3 \backslash \bar{U}_1,
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v=1 \text{ on } \partial U_1, \quad v=0 \text{ on } \partial U_3.
\end{equation}
**Do we have $v\geqslant u$ on $U$?**

If $\partial U_i$ are smooth for $i=1,2,3$, then $u\in C(\bar{U})$, $v\in C(\bar{U_3} \backslash U_1)$. $u, v|_{\partial U_1}=1$, $u|_{\partial U_2}=0$ and
$v|_{\partial U_3}=0$. Then $v-u \geqslant 0$ on $\partial U_1$ and $\partial U_2$, by the maximum principle, we have $v\geqslant u$. However, the boundaries we considered here are not smooth.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed, the maximum principle for subharmonic functions (hence for harmonic functions) is valid for domains, independently of the smoothness of their boundaries :

Let $u$ be a subharmonic function on a domain (i.e. open connected set) $D$ in $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^n$), if $\limsup_{z\to\zeta}u(z)\leq 0$ for all $\zeta\in\partial D$, then $u\leq 0$ on $D$,

See e.g. Theorem 2.3.1 in the book by T. Ransford, Potential theory in the complex plane.

Concerning existence (and uniqueness) of a solution to the Dirichlet problem, the following holds true (see Corollary 4.2.6 of the above-mentioned book):

Let $D$ be a domain with non-polar (intuitively not too small) boundary, and let $\phi:\partial D\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function, continuous on $\partial D$. Then there exists a unique bounded harmonic function $h$ on $D$ such that $\lim_{z\to\zeta}h(z)=\phi(\zeta)$ for nearly every $\zeta\in\partial D$ (nearly meaning outside a set of capacity zero). If the domain is regular (with respect to the Dirichlet problem) the limit holds for all $\zeta\in\partial D$.

Comment: Let $w=v-u$ on $U$. Since the boundaries are bad, we don't have $u(x)\to 1$ when $x \to \partial U_1$ and $u(x) \to 0$ when $x \to \partial U_2$. The same is for $v$. How can you get $\lim sup w(x) \ls 0$ when $x \to \partial U$?

Comment: Sorry for typos. How can you get $\limsup_{x \to \partial U} \leqslant 0$.

Comment: see the assertion I have added about existence of a solution to the Dirichlet problem.

Comment: Let $w=u-v$, I want to prove that $w\leqslant 0$ on $U$. We know that $\lim_{z\to x} u=1$ and $\lim_{z\to x} v=1$ for nearly every $x\in \partial U_1$. $\lim_{z\to x} u=0$ for nearly every $x\in \partial U_2$ and $v\geqslant 0$ on $\partial U_2$. Then $\limsup_{z\to x} w \leqslant 0$ for \textbf{nearly} every $x\in \partial U$. It's not enough for the condition of maximum principle you mentioned.

Comment: Actually, the fact that $\limsup_{z\to\zeta}w(z)\leq 0$ for nearly every $\zeta\in\partial D$ is sufficient to deduce that $w\leq 0$ on $D$, see the extended maximum principle, Theorem 3.6.9 of the book by Ransford.